# lodash map several arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have a json  with a several arrays of objects.

```
{
  "results":[{
    "id_pk": "1",
    "bookings": [{
      "id": 1,
      "id": 2,
    }]
  },{
    "id_pk": "2",
    "bookings": [{
      "id": 3,
      "id": 4,
    }]
  },{
    "id_pk": "3",
    "bookings": [{
      "id": 5,
      "id": 6,
    }]
  }]
}
```

and my goal is to get the id of each " id_pk " using _.map() of lodash

and my code looks like this. Is this a correct format how to get the id ?

```
_.map(results, (r) => _.map(r.bookings, 'id') )
```

Comment: does it work? what result are you getting?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/naZJG this kind of result i'm getting right now

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/k0Ltv my goal is look like this or with 0:1,2 |
1:3,4 | 2:5,6| commas

Comment: there is typo(?) in your json:{"id": 1,"id": 2} is not a valid object

Comment: The first image is useless. Please provide the desired output as text in your question. Also `result` is not a variable, but a property. So please show the connection between your input and your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could get all `id` values by reducing the outer array and mapping all `id` of `booking` array and join the id for an new object.

```js
var data = { results: [{ id_pk: "1", bookings: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }] }, { id_pk: "2", bookings: [{ id: 3 }, { id: 4 }] }, { id_pk: "3", bookings: [{ id: 5 }, { id: 6 }] }] },
    ids = data.results.reduce((r, a, i) => (r[i] = a.bookings.map(b => b.id).join(), r), {});

console.log(ids);
```